# I have an issue updating pip for installing python packages

Tags: python, module, pip, package, installation

[image]

I wanted to install a package for python, but it told me my pip was not up to date and I should update it. I tried to do so and this is the result. Can someone explain this to me and tell me how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of `pip` installed.

When you called `pip --version`, the package it looks at is within

```
C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\lib\site-packages
```

When you called `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, the package that was "already up-to-date" is located in

```
C:\users\rule\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
```

To use the `pip` package that is already up-to-date, you can either `CD` into this directory and call `pip`, or (better yet), change your PATH variable from the prior path to the latter.

To edit PATH environmental variables, you can [reference this page.](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) Look for the path that I listed first, and replace it with the path I listed second.